# Identifying $\mathbb T^1$ with the interval of length $1$, and $\int_{\mathbb T^1} f(x)\, dx=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Learning Functional analysys theory, I have come across this situation.

Let $\mathbb T^1=\mathbb R /\mathbb Z, f: \mathbb T^1 \to \mathbb C.$

My book says that

we can identify $\mathbb T^1$ with the interval whose length is $1$, and we have $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb T^1} f(x)\, dx=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$.

However, I don't know why we can do this.

I know $\mathbb T^1=S^1$ (Circle), but why can we identify this with the interval of length $1$ ?

And how can we get $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb T^1} f(x)\, dx=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ ?

---

(Here is my monology)

If we can identify with the interval of length $1$, there exists $a\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $\mathbb T^1 \cong [a, a+1]$, and I get $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb T^1} f(x)\, dx=\int_a^{a+1} f(x) \, dx=\int_0^1 f(y+a)\, dy$. (I don't know why this is equal to $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$.

---

So, my question is

・Why can we identify $\mathbb T^1$ with the interval of length $1$ ?

・How can we get $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb T^1} f(x)\, dx=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ ?

Answer (score 0):

- Regard $$g:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow [0,1]: [x]\mapsto |x|-\left\lfloor |x|\right\rfloor$$
- $\int_\mathbb{T} f(t)dt$ is then defined by $\int_0^1 f(g^{-1}(t))dt$.

Comment: Could you explain why $\int_0^1 f(t) dt$ is defined by $\int_0^1 f(g^{-1}(t)) dt$ ? I'm confused because I've never seen such statement. @SacAndSac

Comment: I wanted to write $\int_\mathbb{T} f(x)dx$ (edited). Indeed, $\mathbb{T}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so you need to define what is $\int_\mathbb{T} f(x)dx$. Here, you do it by identifying $\mathbb{T}$ as $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: With the notation $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$, it is implied that it's $\int_0^1 f(g^{-1}(x)) dx$